# Count multidimensional array keys with specific value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, count

I've got an array and I need count the keys with a specific value, which is proving to be a nightmare.

```
Array([0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [ruleid] => 1
        [1] => Test Outbound Life 1
        [rule_name] => Test Outbound Life 1
        [2] => Life Insurance
        [product_type] => Life Insurance
        [3] => 1
        [status] => 1
        [4] => 1000
        [priority] => 1000
        [5] => 100
        [quantity] => 100
        [6] => 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-
        [dayofweek] => 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-
        [7] => 2
        [income] => 2
        [8] => external/arc.php
        [integrationfile] => external/arc.php
        [9] => 1
        [partnerid] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [ruleid] => 2
        [1] => Test Outbound Life 2
        [rule_name] => Test Outbound Life 2
        [2] => Life Insurance
        [product_type] => Life Insurance
        [3] => 1
        [status] => 1
        [4] => 800
        [priority] => 800
        [5] => 100
        [quantity] => 100
        [6] => 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-
        [dayofweek] => 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-
        [7] => 2
        [income] => 2
        [8] => test.php
        [integrationfile] => test.php
        [9] => 1
        [partnerid] => 1
    ) )
```

The array will be generated dynamically so the same array will appear in the array.

I want to count how many times the same ruleid appears is it will look like this:

```
Array{ 
   [1] => 1
   [2] => 1
}
```

Update: I need to count how many times ruleid = 2 or how many times ruleid = 1

Comment: `array_count_values(array_column($yourArray, 'ruleid'))` should do it

Answer (score 0):

So you want to count the number of time each `ruleid` appears inside an array.
Let's call this array `$count`. This is how I'd do it.

```
$count = array();
foreach($arrays as $array) { // $arrays is your big ass array containing arrays
    // increment the value with the key corresponding to ruleid (improved by JustOnUnderMillions)
    $count[$array['ruleid']] = isset($count[$array['ruleid']]) ? ($count[$array['ruleid']] + 1) : 1;
}
print_r(count); // should give you what you're looking for
```

Comment: Better do ` $count[$array['ruleid']] = isset( $count[$array['ruleid']]) ? $count[$array['ruleid']]+1:1;` first time the key is set to `NULL` PHP 5.6 -- ignore this !!

Comment: Better test like that: `$count['test'] ++; var_export($count['test']);`   ;) my fault.

Comment: Finally `phpunit` will not break on this case because of `Notice: Undefined index: ruleid` is prevented ;)

Comment: this looks like it'll just do 2 dimensions at most, ignoring 3+ dimensions

Answer (score 0):

I have worked it out by looping and counting how many times a ruleid appears in an array.

```
foreach ($count as $key => $value) {
            $c = 0;     
            //check that outbound has passed all rules
            foreach ($out as $k => $v) {
                if ($v['ruleid']==$key) {
                    $c +=1;
                }
            }
            if ($c==$value) {
                //add valid outbound to array
                foreach ($out as $k => $v) {
                    if ($v['ruleid']==$key) {
                        $valid[$key] = $v;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The loop checks the ruleid has passed all rules I had already counted in the $count variable.